# How to open TeXworks' TeX root pdf result with arara?

Tags: texworks, arara

Until now I've been using TeXworks to edit my `.tex` projects. When the project is divided in several subfiles I can use `% TeX root=my_main_file.tex` directive in order to compile the main file and not the one it's being edited. Once the file is compiled `my_main_file.pdf` is shown in TeXworks' pdf viewer.

Yesterday I decided to test `arara` because I also wanted to use its `clean` rule. After installing it and (more or less) reading the manual I don't know how to automatically open `my_main_file.pdf` after typesetting `my_subfile`.

`arara` typesetting engine is declared with `$fullname --verbose --log` and `view PDF after running` is marked.

Rule `%arara: pdflatex` on `my_main_file.tex` works as expected: main file is processed and viewed.

Rule `% arara: pdflatex: {files: [ my_main_file ] }` on `my_subfile.tex` works almost as expected: main file is processed but nothing is shown in viewer.

What am I missing?

Comment: In your `arara.log`, there should be a line that looks like `TRACE CommandTrigger - Command: ...`. Could you add this line, from both runs, to the question?

Comment: I believe that you only need `% !TeX program=arara` in the secondary files, and no `arara` directive. Of course the `TeX Root` directive is still needed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<sup>First of all, thanks for giving `arara` a try. `:)` We are working on the new `3.x` series, which will hopefully be the best version ever. `:)`</sup>

When you mark the `View PDF after running` option when configuring the tool, TeXworks will monitor the current  file expecting for changes. If you run `arara` on `foo.tex`, TeXworks will wait for changes in that specific file. Now, when we call `arara` on another file, TeXworks is not aware that it's another file that's being processed, hence not displaying the PDF preview.

We can easily "fix" (technically, it's not a fix, it's just a "Hey, TeXworks! I'm running `foo.tex`, but my main file is `bar.tex`.") this behaviour by adding the following TeXworks directive in our `subfile.tex` file:

```
% !TeX root = mymainfile.tex
Hello world
```

That should do the trick. `:)`

The `arara` directive is not even needed in the included files.

When we use the `% !TeX root` directive provided by TeXworks, the current `$fullname` variable is set to `mymainfile.tex`, so `arara` will read the directives in `mymainfile.tex` instead of the current file.

As egreg mentions in the comment, it's also advisable to include another TeXworks directive, `% !TeX program=arara`, in the secondary file just to make sure `arara` will run. Maybe `arara` isn't selected in the program list. `:)`

Comment: Is it going to be even better than v4.0 ? :P

Comment: @percusse: Uh-oh. `:)`

Comment: It worked! I also added `TeX program` directive but I had to remember (looking TeXworks manual) that it only sets the typesetting program when file is loaded. After that the typesetting program selected on the menu is the one which works.

Comment: @PauloCereda: arara tag ;-)

Comment: @PauloCereda I am sorry, but where can I find the possible directives to be used in `arara` documentation? For example, [in this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/188125/2288), I found that there is a directive called `console` that helps run the command prompt. However, I didn't find any information on it in [arara documentation](http://download.nus.edu.sg/mirror/ctan/support/arara/doc/arara-usermanual.pdf). So, is it already in the documentation and I overlooked it or not?