# How to open AdobeReader with arara?

Tags: programming, viewers, arara, adobe

... strange question you will think and you are right, but there are some features, that are not shown in the PDF-Viewer from TeXworks, [tooltips](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tooltips) for example.

I tried this rule, which executes an arbitrary  commandline-order. I added the last line!

```
!config
# Console rule for arara
# author: Clemens Niederberger
# requires arara 3.0+
identifier: console
name: Console
command: <arara> @{command}
arguments:
- identifier: command
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.command}
  default:  <arara> @{getBasename(file)}.pdf
```

It did not have success:

```
Running Console... 


I'm sorry, but the command from the 'Console' task could not be
found. Are you sure the command 'testfile.pdf' is correct, or even
accessible from the system path?
C:\texlive\2013\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:650: command failed with exit code 1:
java.exe -jar c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/scripts/arara/arara.jar testfile.tex --verbose --log
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear, isn't it? You haven't specified a command at all. You've just tried to execute the name of the `pdf`. Since `testfile.pdf` is not a command on your system, `arara` rightly complains that it cannot find it. You need to give it the command for starting Adobe reader. That is, how would you open `testfile.pdf` in Adobe reader from the command line? I can't tell you this as I don't know. On GNU/Linux, I'd use `acroread testfile.pdf`. You need to figure out the command for your system.

Comment: Mmmh, normaly `start` is the windows-order to open a programm. It does not work, mmmh.

Comment: Get it working without `arara` first - just from the command line. Once you know the command, then you will know at least what you need the `arara` rule to do. If you don't know that, it will be hard to get it to do it.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139055/39222) help at all? Note that I know less than nothing about Windows so I won't know if something looks crazy weird...

Comment: Ah, I see - I will read this answer tomorow   in detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, we could do it this way ("but"...)

```
% arara: console: { command: cmd /c start FILE.pdf}
```

This is for `windows`, I am sure, there is an analogon for Linux.

This works, that means it opens the AdobeReader, "but" it gives:

```
! I can't write on file `FILE.pdf'.
(Press Enter to retry, or Control-Z to exit; default file extension is `.pdf')
Please type another file name for output:
```

I do not know, what I could do better here. So I think, the authors should assume it `;)`

PS: Use the original `console`-rule for this:

```
!config
# Console rule for arara
# author: Clemens Niederberger
# requires arara 3.0+
identifier: console
name: Console
command: <arara> @{command}
arguments:
- identifier: command
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.command}
```

Comment: 'ello! I'll take a look later on today. Stay tuned. `:)`

Comment: In GNU/Linux, you'd just need a rule which would execute `acroread` with `filename.pdf` as the sole argument. It is quite straightforward since you use a command to start the application anyway. (You may wrap it in fancy ways to make clicking icons or selecting from a menu execute the command, but you are basically executing the command.) I just have no idea how to translate this to Windows!